Kurdish Language Support in Unity 3d
I have been searching a lot regarding using Kurdish Language which has unicode characters in Unity 3d. I found an Arabic support package which contains many characters similar to kurdish, however there are still some characters that cannot be rendered correctly.
example: ڵ  ە  ڤ
These letters are not arabic letters, that is why it is not rendered correctly.
I tried installing an Arabic support package for unity.
Look at this image, this is what Unity is showing me


it should show the text like below:

I appreciate your Help

Is this https://github.com/Konash/arabic-support-unity? I'd reach out to the author of the package in question to ask them to extend it (it's an open source project). For example, that package already supports several Persian characters, such as چ, which I see in your sample. Given that, they may be able to extend it to include Kurdish. Otherwise you can attempt to add the characters yourself. I don't believe there's an simple answer to your question beyond "you or someone else needs to add the support to a plugin."

@RobNapier  Thanks for your reply, I have downloaded the exact same package you mentioned, the missing characters are   ڵ  ە  ڤ ێ   I appreciate your help

@RobNapier the package converts Arabic script text to Arabic Presentation Form characters, only certain Arabic script languages can be supported this way. The presentation forms are for compatibility with older standards, such as Code page 864. Usually its used with a rewrite of the string from logical to visual order.

@Andj Ah; I hadn't dug into the code. Yeah, using Presentation Form characters is very limited and inflexible. That approach isn't going to work here. I do see this, however, which brings Harfbuzz into Unity, and that should be able to do it. https://github.com/ammariqais/SkiaForUnity

@RobNapier, that looks promising Harfbuzz support is definitely needed. Although, I am curious what library they are using for bidirectional support.

looks like Skia uses a combination of freetype2, icu, and harfbuzz.

Create a JSON file for Kurdish translations. Each entry should have a key and the corresponding translation. For instace:
Key, English, Kurdish
welcome_message, "Welcome", "بەخێربێی"
start_button, "Start", "دەستپێکردن"

Can you explain how this will allow it to render Kurdish correctly? I'm not sure this is an answer to the question.

The issue is, unity is not rendering some words properly, for دەستپێکردن the letter ێ will not be rendered properly.
